# Canvas wont hide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

My HTML5 Canvas element doesn't seem to hide.

I created a timer that should hide the element when the timer reaches 0, I tested this with an alert flag and that worked fine.

Issue:

```
if (TotalSeconds <= 0)
{
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
}
```

Entire code:

```
// Create the canvas
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 512;
canvas.height = 480;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// Background image
var bgReady = false;
var bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.onload = function () {
    bgReady = true;
};
bgImage.src = "images/background.png";

// Hero image
var heroReady = false;
var heroImage = new Image();
heroImage.onload = function () {
    heroReady = true;
};
heroImage.src = "images/hero.png";

// Monster image
var monsterReady = false;
var monsterImage = new Image();
monsterImage.onload = function () {
    monsterReady = true;
};
monsterImage.src = "images/flamingo.png";

// Game objects
var hero = {
    speed: 256 // movement in pixels per second
};
var monster = {};
var monstersCaught = 0;

// Handle keyboard controls
var keysDown = {};

addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
}, false);

// Reset the game when the player catches a monster
var reset = function () {
    hero.x = canvas.width / 2;
    hero.y = canvas.height / 2;

    // Throw the monster somewhere on the screen randomly
    monster.x = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64));
    monster.y = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 64));
};

// Update game objects
var update = function (modifier) {
    if (38 in keysDown) { // Player holding up
        hero.y -= hero.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (40 in keysDown) { // Player holding down
        hero.y += hero.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (37 in keysDown) { // Player holding left
        hero.x -= hero.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (39 in keysDown) { // Player holding right
        hero.x += hero.speed * modifier;
    }

    // Are they touching?
    if (
        hero.x <= (monster.x + 32)
        && monster.x <= (hero.x + 32)
        && hero.y <= (monster.y + 32)
        && monster.y <= (hero.y + 32)
    ) 
    {
        ++monstersCaught;
        reset();
    }
    if (hero.x <= 0)
    {
        hero.x = 510
    }
    if (hero.y <= 0)
    {
        hero.y = 478
    }

};
CreateTimer(5);
var Timer;
var TotalSeconds;


function CreateTimer(Time) {
Timer = $("#timer").text();
TotalSeconds = Time;

UpdateTimer()
window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);
}

function Tick() {
TotalSeconds -= 1;
UpdateTimer()
window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);
}

function UpdateTimer() {
$("#timer").text(TotalSeconds);

if (TotalSeconds <= 0)
{
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
}
}

// Draw everything
var render = function () {
    if (bgReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
    }

    if (heroReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(heroImage, hero.x, hero.y);
    }

    if (monsterReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(monsterImage, monster.x, monster.y);
    }

    // Score
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 250, 250)";
    ctx.font = "24px Helvetica";
    ctx.textAlign = "left";
    ctx.textBaseline = "top";
    ctx.fillText("Flamingos slaughtered: " + monstersCaught, 32, 32);
    ctx.textAlign = "right";
    ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";
    ctx.fillText("Time left: " + TotalSeconds, 150,32);
};

// The main game loop
var main = function () {
    var now = Date.now();
    var delta = now - then;

    update(delta / 1000);
    render();

    then = now;
};

// Let's play this game!
reset();
var then = Date.now();
setInterval(main, 1); // Execute as fast as possible
```

The html is just `<canvas></canvas>`

Pretty new to this so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This does not hide the canvas but clear the context, which means it's clear the drawn shape on canvas

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Comment: So if i was to remove one of the old pieces of text using this 'Context clear' how would i do it?

Comment: context clear is enough for remove the drawn shape from canvas, but does remove all shape.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it by appying a CSS style for it:

```
if (TotalSeconds <= 0) {
    ctx.canvas.style.display = 'none';
}
```

and to reveal it again simple use `block` or `inline-block` instead of `none`.

If you want to hide it but keep its space you can use:

```
ctx.canvas.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

You can also remove it completely from the DOM tree by using:

```
parent.removeChild(canvasElement);
```

where `parent` is the container element (for example `document.body` as you are using now) and `canvasElement` is a reference is your canvas.

All that being said - if you want to just *clear* the canvas then you need to stop the loop you have running. You can use for example a flag to do this:

```
function Tick() {
    TotalSeconds--;
    UpdateTimer();
    if (TotalSeconds > 0) setTimeout(Tick, 1000); // only loop if sec > 0
}
```

and then clear it as you already do.

Hope this helps!